# Wait for all methods to finish before loading the view IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a method which calls a web server, and I wish to wait until this method is finished before showing the UIViewController.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you moving to this UIViewController? I would suggest you to wait for the response before doing the push or model animation

Comment: @ACB i'm moving with a push, how can i wait for the response ?

Comment: How are you making the webservice call? Do you have a delegate method to wait for the didFinish? Can you please post it?

Comment: when facebook shifted from html5 to native code for ios, they posted this http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-rebuilding-facebook-for-ios/10151036091753920 .. check "(Re-)Building for speed" section.. might be helpful ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call webserver via an http request, or something similar, you can set a custom delegate method for the `didFinish` event and show your `viewController` here.

Take a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Comment: Ok thanks i just solved using [request startSynchronous] instead of     [request startAsynchronous]

Comment: @Pach, another some more elegant way is to use the asyn method and show a loading message in your viewcontroller. Once you got the response in your delegate, you can show the other ui elements in that view.

Comment: @Pach : be careful that startSynchronous is a blocking call... it blocks everything except to the thread who is performing the request. the UI is also blocked, and this is not a good thing. especially if you have a poor connection, and you want to cancel your request without waiting for timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grand central dispatch (GCD), heres a example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Web Service Calls

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //UI Stuff
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should request data before you show your view controller.
Then, using designated initialized, open view controller and show his data.
Example (with AFNetworking framework)

```
[[AFAppDotNetAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"stream/0/posts/stream/global" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);
    MyModel model = [self parse:json];
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithData:model];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

} failure:nil];
```